# JPA query timeout parameters ignored but @Transaction annotation works

Tags: java, spring, jpa, timeout, jpa-2.0

I want JPA queries made by my Spring Boot application to a Postgres database to timeout after 5 seconds.

I have created this 20 seconds query to test timeouts:

```
@Query(value = "select count(*) from pg_sleep(20)", nativeQuery = true)
int slowQuery();
```

I've set the following properties in `application.config`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=3000
javax.persistence.query.timeout=5000
```

But the query does not timeout after 3s or 5s (it still takes 20s to execute).

Strangely, if I annotate `slowQuery` with `@Transactional(timeout = 10)`, it times out after 10s or so.

I would prefer not to annotate every query. I'm using JPA 2.0 and the Tomcat connection pool.

What magic is required to make the timeout work just by setting them in application properties file?

Comment: Can you check following https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/setting#Query_Hints_

Comment: Can you try using `spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout`

Comment: Have you tried `spring.transaction.default-timeout=[milliseconds]` in `application.properties` ?

Comment: Did you got any answer for the above? I am facing the exact problem?

Comment: Was never able to try the solution. I ended up putting the timeouts in my JDBC connection string, using MS SQLServer specific construct.

Comment: @ixe013 is it socketTimeout in the string like


 jdbc:mariadb:aurora://myHost/db?socketTimeout=0

Comment: I don't know MariaDB @Nayeem, but what I ended up doing with SQL Server looks more like this [MariaDB query timeout parameter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#set-a-query-timeout)

Answer (score 9):

To make the timeout generic, in your JpaConfiguration, when you declare the PlatformTransactionManager Bean, you can set the default timeout of the transactions:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    txManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    txManager.setDefaultTimeout(10); //Put 10 seconds timeout
    return txManager;
}
```

PlatformTransactionManager inherits AbstractPlatformTransactionManager which contains that method:

```
    /**
     * Specify the default timeout that this transaction manager should apply
     * if there is no timeout specified at the transaction level, in seconds.
     * <p>Default is the underlying transaction infrastructure's default timeout,
     * e.g. typically 30 seconds in case of a JTA provider, indicated by the
     * {@code TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT} value.
     * @see org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition#TIMEOUT_DEFAULT
     */
    public final void setDefaultTimeout(int defaultTimeout) {
        if (defaultTimeout < TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
            throw new InvalidTimeoutException("Invalid default timeout", defaultTimeout);
        }
        this.defaultTimeout = defaultTimeout;
    }
```